# Transpose a nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

I would like to transpose a nested list. Assume the following nested list x is given:

```
a <- list(c("a","b","c","d"))
b <- list(c("d","c","b","a"))
c <- list(c("4","3","2","1"))
d <- list(c("1","2","3","4"))

x <- list(a,b,c,d)
```

The outcome should be a nested list where the first column of the original list x is the first nested list element, that is "a","d","4","1", the second column is the second nested list element, i.e. "b","c","3","2" and so on. In the end the structure is kind of a transpose of the original structure. How can this be done in R?

Comment: `library(purrr) ; x %>% simplify_all() %>% transpose() %>% simplify_all() %>% map(list)` if you want the vectors transposed but the structure the same, though it's really unnecessarily nested.

Comment: @alistaire thanks, but if for example one vector consists of integers instead if characters, this does not work anymore.

Comment: Vectors can only hold one type; `purrr` won't let you simplify characters and integers without explicitly coercing to one type, e.g. `x %>% simplify_all() %>% map(as.character) %>% transpose() %>% simplify_all() %>% map(list)`. If you prefer, `data.table::transpose` will silently coerce.

Comment: alright I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(y) do.call(rbind, y)))
relist(m1, skeleton = x)
```

Comment: nice thx. Is that also feasible for big data structures, like lists of large matrices? My MWE was not so good, I should have used matrices instead.

Comment: @user3032689  I haven't tested for big datasets.  You can also check the `transpose` from `purrr`

Comment: please see the edited question. purrr does not help me there either.

Comment: @user3032689  Can you post that as a new question?

Comment: yep posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293098/transpose-a-nested-list-of-different-datatypes

Answer (score 4):

We could also do without `lapply` (using matrix):

```
relist(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 4, byrow = T), skeleton = x)
```

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)
a <- list(c("a","b","c","d"))
b <- list(c("d","c","b","a"))
c <- list(c("4","3","2","1"))
d <- list(c("1","2","3","4"))
x <- list(a,b,c,d)

f_akrun <- function(x) {m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(y) do.call(rbind, y)));relist(m1, skeleton = x);}
f_m0h3n <- function(x) {relist(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = length(x[[1]][[1]]), byrow = T), skeleton = x)}

setequal(f_akrun(x), f_m0h3n(x))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(f_akrun(x), f_m0h3n(x))

# Unit: microseconds
   # expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 # f_akrun(x) 135.591 137.301 144.3545 138.585 148.422 334.484   100
 # f_m0h3n(x) 110.782 111.638 116.5477 112.493 117.412 212.153   100
```